# How to execute code on rollback of JPA transaction

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, rollback

I'm using EclipseLink  (JPA).  I've got a service that renames some files and calls a DAO which updates database tables accordingly. This happens in a transaction, and there might be a rollback.  So that the DB stays in sync with the file system, I want to at least attempt to revert the file rename, and log an error when that can't be done.  Is there some way to register a Runnable (or similar) with the transaction so that it executes on rollback?

EclipseLink has SessionEventListener which can respond to pre (preRollbackTransaction) and post rollback events, and I can get the transaction from the EntityManager.  So I was thinking I could create some kind of global registry.  However, I can't figure out how to match up the SessionEvent available in the listener with the EntityTransaction available from EntityManager.getTransaction().  Is there some way to do this, or is there a more straightforward way to provide a callback on rollback?

I could simply use a try-catch and execute the revert code in the catch, but it is possible the rollback will occur after the session method is returned (i.e. higher up the stack).

Comment: You can register your event listener with the session (A UnitOfWork instance) under the EntityManager directly, which might give you more visibility and control. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager which shows getting a connection - the JPA 1.0 approach gets the UOW first. Otherwise, the transaction object is really just a wrapper over the session calls to the UnitOfWork - it isn't something used by EclipseLInk native code. Any context you need would need to be set in the EntityManager or UOW directly.

Comment: @Chris: So, if I'm understanding correctly, I could do something like `entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).getEventManager().addListener(listener);`.  However, I'm unclear about how to limit this to a transaction.  Would I give my listener a ref to the SessionEventManager, and then have that listener remove itself on both postRollbackTransaction (after doing its revert code) and postCommit?

Comment: Use entityManager.unwrap(UnitOfWork.class).getEventManager().addListener(listener); . The UnitOfWork is associated to the transaction context and is a listener (if using JTA) so it can perform pre/post commit operations just as you need to. Any listeners added to it are only added to it, so won't see or be involved in any other transactions. Listeners added to the main session propagate up to client sessions and UnitOfWork: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Sessions_(ELUG)